# I am trying to use insert query correctly in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying for about an hour to get this insert into tag to work. The thing is I need to insert a customer into the customer table without the picture column and with an autoincrement-ed customer ID. What I have so far is this:

```
INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, mi, nickname, company_name, title, address, city, region, postal_code, country, phone, fax, e-mail, test) 
VALUES('Tweedle', 'Dee', 'D', 'Twee', 'Shirts Emporium', 'Manager', '2448 Peanut Ave.', 'Dallas','Texas', 75001, 'USA', 2145545545, 2145565565, 'tweedledee221@stories.com', 'Val1')
```

What I meant by doesn't work is that it had an error on line 1 that I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mysql doesn't like** your column **e-mail**

use

```
INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, mi, nickname
  , company_name, title, address, city, region, postal_code
   , country, phone, fax, `e-mail`, test) 
VALUES('Tweedle', 'Dee', 'D', 'Twee', 'Shirts Emporium'
     , 'Manager', '2448 Peanut Ave.', 'Dallas','Texas', 75001
     , 'USA', 2145545545, 2145565565, 'tweedledee221@stories.com', 'Val1')
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did work I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do

```
INSERT INTO customers VALUES('Tweedle', 'Dee', 'D', 'Twee', 'Shirts Emporium'
 , 'Manager', '2448 Peanut Ave.', 'Dallas','Texas', 75001
 , 'USA', 2145545545, 2145565565, 'tweedledee221@stories.com', 'Val1')
```

The columns in the inserts are not needed at all.